# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'ewmstd'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statistics

I get the error message: `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'ewmstd'`

I have seen exactly the same issue for the `EWM function` in a previous stackoverflow post with **the solution** as follows:

```
df = pd.ewm(halflife=0.5).mean()
```

I therefore replicate exactly the same solution (which works for **ewm**) aside from replacing `ewm` with `ewmstd` as follows:

```
df = pd.ewmstd(halflife=0.5).mean()
```

However, i get the same error message. I also try different variants, but get the same error.

Have i called the function incorrectly or how does one call it ?
(i use the docs from here:  [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.ewmstd.html](http:///https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.ewmstd.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have used `df = pd.ewm(halflife=0.5).std()` which yields results on the DataFrame.
Might i expect this to provide the same output ?